# $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n$ where $x_{n+1}=\left(1-\frac1{2n}\right)x_n+\frac1{2n}x_{n-1}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

let $x_0 = a$ and $x_1 = b $ , $x_{n+1} = ( 1- \frac{1}{2n}) x_n   +  \frac{1}{2n} x_{n-1}$, $n\ge 1$ find $\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n$?

My attempt: I take  $x_n = a + (b-a) + \dots + (x_n - x_{n-1})$

after that  that I am not able to proceed further.

Please help me  or  any hints/solution will be appreciated.

Thank you and thanks  in advance  for giving hints/solutions

Comment: Hint: find the formula for $x_{n+1} - x_n$, and see if their sum looks familiar.

Comment: A hint:  Observe that $$x_{n+1}-x_n=-\frac{1}{2n}(x_n-x_{n-1}).$$

Comment: The accepted answer only shows that the limit exists...

Comment: To compute the limit note that $x_{n + 1}  - x_n  =  - \frac{1}{{2n}}(x_n  - x_{n - 1} )$ implies $x_{n + 1}  - x_n  = \frac{{( - 1)^n }}{{2^n n!}}(b - a)$ via induction. Thus, $$
x_N  - x_0  = (b - a)\sum\limits_{n = 0}^{N - 1} {\frac{{( - 1)^n }}{{2^n n!}}}  \Rightarrow \mathop {\lim }\limits_{N \to  + \infty } x_N  = a + (b - a)\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^n }}{{2^n n!}}}  = a + (b - a)e^{ - 1/2} .
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ converges if and only if it is a Cauchy sequence. What's more the recursive definition gives:

$\vert x_{n+1}-x_n\vert=\frac{1}{2n}\vert x_n-x_{n-1}\vert=...=\frac{1}{2^n \cdot n!} \vert b-a\vert $

Which then means that for all $n,k\in \mathbb{N}$:

$\vert x_{n+k}-x_n \vert \leq \overset{k}{\underset{l=1}{\sum}}\vert x_{n+l}-x_{n+l-1}\vert\leq \vert b-a\vert \cdot \overset{k}{\underset{l=1}{\sum}}\frac{1}{2^{n+l} \cdot (n+l)!}\leq 
\vert b-a\vert \cdot \overset{k}{\underset{l=1}{\sum}}\frac{1}{2^{n+l}}\ $

And for all $\epsilon>0$ and $n$ large enough we'll obtain that:

$\vert x_{n+k}-x_n \vert <\epsilon$

Which means that the sequence is Cauchy.